# Laptop Keyboard Characters not corresponding to the right key, and some don't work

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, hardware-failure

I'm using Fujitsu Lifebook LH532, my computer's keyboard suddenly get into a trouble. The case is like this:

When I press "W", "E", "R", "Y", "[", "K", "L", TAB, ENTER and the WINDOWS KEY, it doesn't work, but when I hold the "Q" and "W" key together, it would do something like this:

"E" = "3"

"R" = "T"

"K" = "J"

"L" = "P"

"[" = "-"

TAB = "1"

And other keys still don't work.
Is this the problem of my keyboard being haywired or is it broken? I haven't drop the laptop once, and never hit it with my hard fist, I haven't change the motherboard since I bought this computer around 2 years ago, and finally the computer've been on for over half an year (Except Updates and the Do-It-Yourself Fixing of keyboard which is 2 minutes ago). Is that the keyboard starting to get weird because I haven't turn it off for over half a year?

Comment: Have you tested with a USB keyboard?

Comment: If a USB keyboard works then you may well need to repair or replace the laptop keyboard. It could be something simple like a loose connection or damaged cable between keyboard and motherboard. Some laptop models are known for this kind of issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yup the USB one is working, and this question is typed using USB keyboard. Thanks for telling me that, but I remember that if the connector lost connection with the motherboard the keyboard would be disabled entirely, isn't it?

Comment: Not if cable is connected but **damaged**. Like I said this can be caused by a design fault where part of the laptop presses against the cable.

Comment: Oh thanks to tell me that, but I'll try to send the computer to a repair store, after I can figure the password of the lock, which holds the computer, out.

Comment: Nope the lock is dead, so where's the connector located in my laptop? I couldn't find it at the bottom.

Comment: You might have switched language of your operating system, which will switch your buttons up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the keyboard. It consists of several layers of a film with the conducting traces on them with interconnecting holes between the layers. When the films are damaged or a liquid gets inside, some conducting paths become interconnected. Hence, keys stop working.
This is the case.

You may double-check it by connecting an external USB keyboard. If it works fine - you just need to replace a built-in KB.